# No Entry Error when trying to install Karma js

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, yeoman, karma-runner

I'm super new to all of these frameworks.  I'm following tutorials that want me to use Karma for unit testing.  According to [NPMjs.org - karma](https://npmjs.org/package/karma) The build is failing
[image: karma fail]

Is this ENOENT error:
after running `npm install -g karma`
a result of this failing build?  Or is it windows?  Maybe a system enviroment variable error.
Are there prerequisite npm modules I must install before karma will properly install?
I'm uncertain on where to start debugging this problem.
[image: ENOENTY]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Karma depends on `ws`: this is this package that npm can't build.

It builds fine on Mac Os but doesn't on Windows: there's [an issue on karma's GitHub](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/546) referring to ws' github issues ([here](https://github.com/einaros/ws/issues/194), [here](https://github.com/einaros/ws/issues/240) and [there](https://github.com/einaros/ws/issues/191)). I'd suggest you to take a look a the possible solutions, but unfortunately it doesn't look like this is a resolved matter.

Comment: Any suggestions to karma that work's similar and on windows?  I'm really new to unit testing and all these front end frameworks.  Or would you suggest I just skip lol.

Comment: Looks like [you can try installing in an administrator shell](https://github.com/einaros/ws/issues/240#issuecomment-24423578)..